# WCF Service's Multiple App Domains Causing Issues With Concurrency

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, singleton, appdomain

I have a WCF Service Endpoint that is defined with the following ServiceBehavior attribute.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

I am having issues with a call within my service that needs to guarantee that an object is only created once. The following code is called within my service.

```
public class MySingletonDataProvider{
     private static MySingletonDataProvider _instance;
     private static readonly object _lock = new object();

     public static MySingletonProvider Create(){

          lock(_lock){

              if(_instance == null){
                 _instance = new MySingletonProvider();
                 Log.Info("New Instance Created " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName");
              }

              return _instance;
          }
     }
}
```

When this is hit, we are typically getting 3-5 logs such as the following:

```
- "New Instance Created 123252352323623"
- "New Instance Created 423523562362362"
- "New Instance Created 235623623462366"
```

Showing that multiple AppDomains are able to execute the code within the lock. This is causing huge issues. What is the solution so that I can guarantee that this instance is only created once?

Answer (score 0):

CLR creates new MySingletonDataProvider instance for each AppDomain, thus you have separate locking objects. I'd suggest to use some kind of inter-process synchronization primitives, as mutexes, for example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx